# Bootstrap custom navbar collapse button not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navbar, customized, is collapsing correctly but the menu button during collapse isn't showing up. If I click around the area, I can find a link that lets me drop the dropdown, but I can't see the button. I think maybe my customization is causing it to be invisible or behind the actual navbar. Here is my HTML/CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">



<style>
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #141414;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.navbar-nav > li{
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:15px;

}


/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);


}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #85b0be;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-logo {
  margin-right: 60%;
}


.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li>a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  bottom: 0;
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.text-my-own-color {
  color: #85b0be !important; 
}




.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited {
    background-color: #85b0be !important;
    border-color: white !important;}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm justify-content-end">
<a class="navbar-logo" href="#">
    <img style="opacity:0.7;filter:alpha(opacity=40); width:50px;" src="{% static 'img/logo.bmp' %}" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-bolt color-white"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Running the code above will generate a navbar that collapses at a certain screen width, but I just can't find where the collapse button is going. Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you suspect it to be behind something, try to give it a high z-index and see what happens. Using the developer console in your browser will probably help you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```css
  .navbar-toggler {
    background-color: orange !important;
  }
```

You can also check if the CSS works without the `!important`. If so, you can drop it. Much cleaner CSS.